# ng-disable with number failed

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to use `ng-disabled` to disable a button but failed. Here is the HTML part:

```
<tr ng-repeat="eachdata in tabledb">
    <td>{{eachdata.paid}}</td>
</tr>

<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="process(eachdata)" 
        ng-disabled="eachdata.paid">
```

The console.log showed that `eachdata.paid`: "0" or "1". I hope to disable the button when paid:"1".

So I also tried

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="process(eachdata)" 
        ng-disabled="Boolean(Number('1'))">
```

but still it is not working.

I checked the reference of convert type in Javascript. It supposed to be true when converting number 1 to boolean and false when converting number 0 to boolean. Can anyone explain that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why so much confusion regarding a simple thing.First as per your question button is out of scope to `ng-repeat`.So I assume it is includes in ng-repeat.

```
<tr ng-repeat="eachdata in tabledb">
    <td>{{eachdata.paid}}</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="process(eachdata)" 
        ng-disabled="checkIfDisabled(eachdata.paid)"></td>
</tr>
```

In controller define `checkIfDisabled` function

```
$scope.checkIfDisabled=function(paid){
  return (paid == "1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the repeated table row before the button, therefore your "eachdata" variable isn't available to the button scope. Include the button inside the td, or elsewhere within the scope of the tr.

Comment: Hi I  have put the button inside the <tr></tr> but still not working. <tr ng-repeat="eachdata in tabledb"><td>{{eachdata.paid}}</td> <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="process(eachdata)" ng-disabled="Boolean(Number('1'))"></td></tr>

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Your button is out of scope from the ng-repeat. If you want the button outside of your table you can maybe use a dummyTag and run the ng-repeat inside it.